# How to guarantee that property is a part of interface?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I have a function that accepts generic type:

```
interface IFilter {
   category: number;
   subject: number;
}

public filter: IFilter;

protected _set<T, U>(key: T, value: U, reset?: true) {
    this.filter[key] = value;
}
```

How to be ensure that `key: T` is a part of `IFilter`, I mean it can accepts only `category` and `subject`. The same question about `value: U`.

I think betters is to pass concrete type as `IFilter` then to do:

```
this.filter = value;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `keyof` and restrict the generic parameter to extend that, and the use a type query for value to ensure the value and the key match:

```
 protected _set<K extends keyof IFilter>(key: K, value: IFilter[K], reset?: true) {
     this.filter[key] = value;
 }

this._set("category", 0) // ok 
this._set("category", "0") // error  category is not string
```